# Partial Truck needs to be identified

Tags: set-identification

I've acquired a partially built truck (2 sets wheels so not huge), of which the bottom section is all I have (from the floor down). There is a transfer on both sides (on red bricks, which made me think of a fire truck, but no luck). This sticker looks like an advertisement or sponsorship logo you might see on a vehicle. It says Octan, then Tele (with the top of the T being a telephone receiver), then a white square with a black border with the initials CB in black typeface in it. It also has a tow hitch on the rear. Any ideas what model number I've got?

Comment: Welcome Paul! Can you add a picture of the build to help us help you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your description of the brick with “transfers”, which I assume are stickers, there is only one set that has Octan and Tele logos on it: [60084 Racing Bike Transporter](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=60084-1&name=Racing%20Bike%20Transporter&category=%5BTown%5D%5BCity%5D%5BRace%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D). This set seems to match the rest of your description as well.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, that's the one. Thank you, now to see if I can build the rest of it.